# PyQT QTextEdit widget with inserting Greek symbols

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am looking for guidance to make QTextEdit widget capable of inserting Greek symbols(omega, delta), the way Microsoft Word does it for example.I know that QTextEdit supports basic HTML tags, like bold/italic but is there a way in QT to make text editing(not necessarily QTextEdit) a little bit easier so that Greek symbols can be inserted in just one click?

Comment: How is it exactly that you would like to be able to insert a symbol? Using a combo box? Entering a series of characters? A keyboard shortcut? Please upload your code so we may understand you better

Answer (score 0):

You might use the `setHtml()` of your text edit and use the html code given [here](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html)

In your case create a button to insert the character code using `insertHtml()`